# ASP.NET MVC and SproutCore

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, sproutcore

Does anyone have any experience of using SproutCore together with ASP.NET MVC? For what I can understand one has to run SproutCore on a Ruby server, although the backend of the application can run ASP.NET MVC. Is it possible host SproutCore on an ISS Server?

Are there any other frameworks like SproutCore that one can integrate into ASP.NET MVC?

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When deployed, SproutCore is only static HTML, CSS & JS files. This means you can serve them from any server: Apache, nginx, IIS or any server that can serve up plain old text files.

Ruby is only used in development mode, it has a server, which keeps track of files that you've changed (to make reloading faster), and a build script which takes the many files (split to make debugging easer) and joins/minifies them. Once built, you can take these files and put them anywhere, no ruby needed.

On your server side, you can use what ever tech you want for authentication/ data persistance. In your case you would use ASP.NET, to write your API that would send and receive JSON (or XML if your so inclined).

See http://wiki.sproutcore.com/w/page/12413020/Todos%2006-Building%20the%20Backend for examples on how you would write your server.